# How to build visualizations as chrome app

Tags: google-chrome, analytics, bigdata, google-chrome-app

I am very much impressed by the way this app was build , https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/visual-history/emnpecigdjglcgfabfnmlphhgfdifaan
I wonder if SAP Lumira was involved in this application, for the live visualitations to work fine. but i am not sure of how it was developed as an app as it can only export as png files and the data can only be from flat files and hana database. Any help to analyse the nature of this application is appreciated.

Comment: The [source](https://code.google.com/p/visual-history-graph/source/browse/) is available. Looks like it's largely based on a few open-source libraries.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think your question is not stated correctly: it's like asking "how to build visualizations for the web" (in other words, it's too broad and it's not specific to Chrome apps). I think what you want is a way to analyze the source of an app. What you can always do for that is:

1. After installing the app you're interested in, visit chrome://extensions.
2. Turn on the Developer mode (a check box in the upper-right corner).
3. Find the app in the list and note down its app ID.
4. Go to Chrome settings directory, e.g. ~/.config/google-chrome for Linux - the location will depend on the OS and the Chrome channel that you're using.
5. Find the app's installation directory, which will look something like `<Chrome settings directory from #4>/Profile N/Extensions/<app ID>/<app version>`.
6. You will see the entire app's source there.

Specifically for this app, you can see in the sources that it uses something called JavaScript Graph framework (see /canvas.js) together with [D3.js](http://mbostock.github.io/protovis/) (see /protovis-3.2/).

Comment: This may not be related to this question , but can we export the data into an excel sheet, something like this( If user opens facebook website for 7 times in a particular period, it is exported as www.facebook.com in one column and 7 in other column) Is there a way i can achieve this?

Comment: You can collect the information you need in an extension using the [History API](http://chrome-apps-doc.appspot.com/extensions/history.html), then pass it to a companion app using the [chrome.runtime.sendMessage](http://chrome-apps-doc.appspot.com/apps/runtime.html#method-sendMessage) / [chrome.runtime.onMessageExternal](http://chrome-apps-doc.appspot.com/apps/runtime.html#event-onMessageExternal) pair, and finally save it to disk using the [FileSystem API](http://chrome-apps-doc.appspot.com/apps/fileSystem.html) or to Google Drive using SyncFileSystem API.